# How to divide an array into equal parts in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, chunks

I am new to nodejs and i need to divide an array which contain dates on x-axis and its points on y axis and trying to draw a graph using an array to store data for x and y axis to do that i am doing this :

```
while(startDate <= endDate)
{
  arr.push({x:startDate.toISOString().slice(0,10),y: 0});
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1); 
}
```

it will store all the dates from start date to ending date now i need to divide it into weeks so i am finding weeks by :

```
var   Weeks = Math.round((endDate - startDate) / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

now to get on which date there is a point so i do :

```
for (var i = doc.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   for (var j = arr.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (arr[j].x == doc[i].deal_end_date) {
            arr[j].y ++;
          }
        }     
    }
}
```

now this will give me an output as below :

```
startDate: 2017-07-10, endDate: 2017-07-31


arr :
[ { x: '2017-07-10', y: 1 },
      { x: '2017-07-11', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-12', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-13', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-14', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-15', y: 1 },
      { x: '2017-07-16', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-17', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-18', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-19', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-20', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-21', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-22', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-23', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-24', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-25', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-26', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-27', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-28', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-29', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-30', y: 0 },
      { x: '2017-07-31', y: 0 } ]
```

now i need to divide this array i.e arr into weeks and 
i tried

```
var i,j,temparray,chunk = Weeks;
for (i=0,j=arr.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    temparray = arr.slice(i,i+chunk);
}
```

but it stores in temparray as :

```
temparray: [ { x: '2017-07-31', y: 0 } ]
```

and i need my temparray as below :

```
startDate: 2017-07-01 endDate: 2017-07-28 
Weeks: 4
/*temparray[1] should be from arr[0] to arr[6]*/
temparray[1] :
[ { x: '2017-07-01', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-02', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-03', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-04', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-05', y: 1 },
  { x: '2017-07-06', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-07', y: 0 }]
/*temparray[2] should be from arr[7] to arr[13]*/
temparray[2] :
[ { x: '2017-07-08', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-09', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-10', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-11', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-12', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-13', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-14', y: 0 }]
/*temparray[3] should be from arr[14] to arr[20]*/
temparray[3] :
[ { x: '2017-07-15', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-16', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-17', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-18', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-19', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-20', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-21', y: 0 }]
/*temparray[4] should be from arr[21] to arr[27]*/
temparray[4] :
[ { x: '2017-07-22', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-23', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-24', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-25', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-26', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-27', y: 0 },
  { x: '2017-07-28', y: 0 }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `fill` and `map`:

```js
function splitArray(array, chunkSize) {
  return Array(Math.ceil(array.length/chunkSize)).fill().map(function(_,i) {
    return array.slice(i * chunkSize, i * chunkSize + chunkSize);
  });
}

var results = splitArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3);
console.log(results);
```

You can adapt it to use dates

Answer (score 2):

With one simple line of code, you may get the solution that may work [up to 3 times](https://jsperf.com/break-array-into-pieces/1) faster than provided above:

```js
const src = [...'abcdefghijklmnop'];

const chunkArr = (arr, size) => arr.reduceRight((res,_,__,self) => [...res, self.splice(0, size)],[]);

console.log(chunkArr(src, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @Alberto Trindade Tavares i just do it by :

```
/* arr is my original array */
var ressu = splitArray(arr, 7);

function splitArray(arr, chunkSize) {
  return Array(Math.ceil(arr.length/chunkSize)).fill().map(function(_,i) {
    return arr.slice(i * chunkSize, i * chunkSize + chunkSize);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by using for loop. This is easy to understand.

```
  function splitToChunks(array, parts) {
        const result = [];
        for (let i = parts; i > 0; i--) {
            result.push(array.splice(0, Math.ceil(array.length / i)));
        }
        return result;
    }
var results = splitToChunks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3);
console.log(results);
```